# How to integrate programmatic configuration in log4j?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2, rollingfileappender, programmatic-config

I am using Log4j version 2.0.1 version and due to organisation policies, I cannot use any higher version for the time-being.

```
group:'org.apache.logging.log4j',name:'log4j-core',version:'2.0.1'
group:'org.apache.logging.log4j',name:'log4j-api',version:'2.0.1'
```

### My Requirements for logging

1. If customDebug=true as environment variable, then enable debug logging
2. There should be 2 logging files generated -- one primary logging (info/debug based on above logs) and error logging.
3. Have a size based rolling strategy
4. The directory of the log files is dynamic.
5. The format should carry the time in certain styling along with thread id.

I tried implementing programmatic configuration of log4j in the following manner --

**CustomConfigFactory.java >>**

```
@Plugin(name = "CustomConfigFactory", category = "JsonConfigurationFactory")
@Order(10)
public class CustomConfigFactory extends JsonConfigurationFactory {

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedTypes() {
        return new String[] {".json"};
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConfiguration(ConfigurationSource cs) {
        try{
            String file = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("customRollingConfiguration.json").getFile()
            cs = new ConfigurationSource(new FileInputStream(new File(file ));
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("ERROR : Exception encountered while initiating configuration source: "+e);
        }
        return new CustomJsonConfiguration(cs);
    }

}
```

**CustomJsonConfiguration.java  >>**

```
public class CustomJsonConfiguration extends JsonConfiguration {

    public CustomJsonConfiguration(final ConfigurationSource configSource) {
        super(configSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doConfigure(){
        try {
            ConfigurationSource source = this.getConfigurationSource();
            Configuration config = CustomConfigFactory.getInstance().getConfiguration(source);

            final Layout layout = PatternLayout.createLayout("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5p [%5T] %c{1}:%L - %m%n",
                config,null,Charset.defaultCharset(),true,false,"","");

            SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy policy = SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("10 MB");
            DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.createStrategy("50", "5", "min", "9", config);

            String logDir = System.getenv("log_dir");
            String primaryLogFile = logDir+"/my_main_log";
            String primaryLogFilePattern = primaryLogFile+"-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz";

            String errorLogFile = logDir+"/my_err_log";
            String errorLogFilePattern = errorLogFile+"-backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz";

            RollingFileAppender appender1 = RollingFileAppender.createAppender(primaryLogFile,
                primaryLogFilePattern,"true", "debugFile","true", "false","false",
                policy, strategy, layout, null, null, null, null, config);
            appender1.start();;

            RollingFileAppender appender2 = RollingFileAppender.createAppender(errorLogFile,
                errorLogFilePattern,"true","errorFile","true","false","false",
                policy, strategy, layout, null,null,null,null, config);
            appender2.start();;

            config.addAppender(appender1);
            config.addAppender(appender2);

            LoggerConfig primaryLoggerConfig = null;
            if(Boolean.valueOf(System.getenv("customDebug")){
                 primaryLoggerConfig = new LoggerConfig("aa.bb.cc.dd",Level.DEBUG,false);
            } else {
                primaryLoggerConfig = new LoggerConfig("aa.bb.cc.dd",Level.INFO,false);
            }
            LoggerConfig errorLoggerConfig = new LoggerConfig("aa.bb.cc.dd",Level.ERROR,false);

            primaryLoggerConfig.addAppender(appender1,null,null);
            errorLoggerConfig.addAppender(appender2,null,null);
            config.addLogger("aa.bb.cc.dd",primaryLoggerConfig);
            config.addLogger("aa.bb.cc.dd",errorLoggerConfig);

            LoggerContext context = new LoggerContext("default_context");
            context.start(config);
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.err.println("");
        }
    }
```

where the aa.bb.cc.dd refers to the package name of the MyClass below.

**MyClass.java** where this logger will be used >>

```
package aa.bb.cc.dd;

public MyClass {
    static final Logger myCustomLog = LogManager.getLogger(MyClass.class);

    void doSomething(){
        myCustomLog.info("Doing something");
    }
}
```

**Sample Test Method** as part of a testng class for testing the above class >>>

```
@Test
public void testDoingSomething(){
    MyClass m1 = new MyClass();
    m1.doSomething();
}
```

But the above doesn't seem to work and none of the log files are getting generated i.e. logging is not working.
I have primarily referred to this for the implementation - -https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customconfig.html#Hybrid

I'd appreciate if anybody could help me out with this implementation. All suggestions welcomed !!!

Thanks in advance.

EDIT >>>
Following is the configuration json after incorporating @VikasSachdeva's comments. The error file is still empty even thought an ERROR condition is being logged in my_main.log

```
{
  "configuration": {
     "name": "RollingKitConfig",
    "Appenders": {
  "appender": [
    {
      "type": "RollingFile",
      "name": "debugFile",
      "fileName": "${env:log_dir}/my_main_log",
      "filePattern": "${env:log_dir  }/my_main_backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz",
      "PatternLayout": {
        "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,nnn} [%-5p] [%5t] [%c{3}:%L] - %m%n"
      },
      "Policies": {
        "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
          "size": "10 MB"
        }
      },
      "DefaultRolloverStrategy": {
        "max": "10"
      },
      "ThresholdFilter": {
        "level": "${env:customDebug:-info}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "RollingFile",
      "name": "errorFile",
      "fileName": "${env:log_dir}/errors.log",
      "filePattern": "${env:log_dir}/errors_backup-%d{MM-dd-yy-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log.gz",
      "PatternLayout": {
        "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,nnn} [%-5p] [%5t] [%c{1}:%L] - %m%n"
      },
      "Policies": {
        "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {
          "size": "10 MB"
        }
      },
      "DefaultRolloverStrategy": {
        "max": "10"
      },
      "ThresholdFilter": {
        "level": "ERROR",
        "onMatch": "ACCEPT",
        "onMisMatch": "DENY"
      }
    }
  ]
},
"Loggers": {
  "logger": [
    {
      "name": "KitLogger",
      "level": "info",
      "additivity": "false",
      "AppenderRef": [
        {
          "ref": "debugFile"
        },
        {
          "ref": "errorFile"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "root": {
    "level": "debug",
    "appender-ref": {
      "ref": "debugFile"
    }
  }
}
  }
}
```

Comment: The implementation you referred is for hybrid implementation i.e. configuration file + programmatic modifications. So, are you using any configuration file. Can you post that ?

Comment: @VikasSachdeva -- thanks. added the configuration json file. So since the log file location is dynamic, the json file does not have any path or name for log file. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pick log file location using environment variables, you can do so using configuration file alone as describe in [log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/lookups.html#EnvironmentLookup)

Considering your environment variable is `log_dir=D:/logs/`. Then you can change your configuration like below -

```
{
    "configuration": {
        "name": "RollingConfig",
        "ThresholdFilter": { "level": "info" },
        "properties": {
            "property": {
                "name": "basePath",
                "value": "${env:log_dir}"
             }
        },
        "appenders": {
            "RollingFile": {
                "name": "debugFile",
                "fileName": "${basePath}my_main.log",
                "filePattern": "${basePath}my_main_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz",
                "PatternLayout": { "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%5T] %c{1}:%L - %m%n" },
                "Policies": {
                    "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": { "size": "10 MB" }
                },
               "DefaultRolloverStrategy": { "max": "10"  }
            },
            "RollingFile": {
                "name": "errorFile",
                "fileName": "${basePath}my_err.log",,
                "filePattern": "${basePath}my_err_%d{yyyyMMdd}.log.gz",
                "thresholdFilter": {
                    "level": "ERROR",
                    "onMatch": "ACCEPT",
                    "onMisMatch": "DENY"
                },
                "PatternLayout": { "pattern": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p [%5T] %c{1}:%L - %m%n" },
                "Policies": {
                     "SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy": {  "size": "10 MB" }
                },
                "DefaultRolloverStrategy": {"max": "10"}
            }
        },
        "loggers": {
            "logger": {
                 "name": "mainLogger",
                 "level": "info",
                 "additivity": "false",
                 "appender-ref": [ 
                                 {"ref": "debugFile"}, 
                                 { "ref":"errorFile"}
                                 ]
            },
            "root": {
                "level": "info",
                 "appender-ref": [ 
                                 {"ref": "debugFile" }, 
                                 { "ref":"errorFile" }
                                 ]
             }
          }
       }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @VikasSachdeva. 1 more issue - I want the errorFile appender to only log ERROR messages. I tried using the Threshold filter but it doesn't seem to work. Any inputs ?

Comment: I updated above answer with threshold filter configuration on errorFile appender.

Comment: The error file is still not logging error messages, although ERROR is getting logged in primary debugFile but not the errorFile.

Comment: You added appender in logger also ? can you post your updated configuration

Comment: updated the json file now. Error case not working for me.

Comment: `root` logger still contain reference to only debugFile appender. It should refe to both appender as I mentioned in answer.

Comment: Also, with configuration mentioned in answer, debugfile will get all logs including ERROR logs. If you want to omit ERROR logs in debug file, some threshold need to be set in that appender also.